# how to remove empty from li in angular 2?

Tags: html, angular

I am working on angular 2?  I am facing an issue when I am fetching data from database generate multiple empty li, because of that my CSS does not work correctly?
look like

```
<li><!--template bindings={}--></li>
```

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter for non-empty values

```
return this.http.get(...).map(res => res.json()).filter(v => !!v)
```

Ensure you have `filter` imported (like `map`)